# Magento losing cookie when login (switch from HTTP to HTTPS)

Tags: magento, session, cookies, https, magento-1.7

I have a Magento 1.7.0.2 installation which loses session data when logging in.

It logs in correctly from main page (HTTP) and works fine until I go to Cart page and click checkout. Then it leads to checkout where I am logged out (already HTTPS) and when I try to login it redirects me to account/dashboard and thus I cannot ever complete an order.

Recently we've changed the server from Litespeed to Apache, I'm not sure if the problem is in Apache configuration because As I change the cookie settings from Magento, it makes no effect.

I've tried setting the domain like ".www.example.com", path to "/", expire time to "5400", no effect.

EDIT: it turns out the cookie is not passed to /checkout/onepage/ request. That is when I click the checkout button. What may be the reason for this?

Comment: Did you try disabling every module?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `System->Configuration->Web->Session Cookie Management->Use HTTP Only` to "No" and clear the cache.

Comment: It doen't help. It works ok the first time a client logs in, after that if you change page or add another product, clicking checkout at the cart and login redirects to to dashboard.